# update state mapping from a different contract

Tags: solidity, remix

I am pretty new to Solidity so here goes. I was wondering if it is possible to update a state mapping present in a contract from another contract. Like so

```
contract A {

    mapping(uint => uint) public nbrVotesOnProposal;
    mapping(uint => address) public proposalOwner;
    uint public proposalId;            

 
}

contract B {

    A public a;

    constructor(address _a) {
        a = A(_a);
    }

    
    function addProposal() payable external {
      
        a.nbrVotesOnProposal[proposalId] = 0;
        a.proposalOwner[proposalId] = msg.sender;
        a.proposalId++;
     }
}
```

I would like to do the things in addProposal.... so updating mappings of another contract.

Is this possible because I can't figure out how. Remix keeps giving me errors.

With Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There are few errors there:

1. `proposalId` variable is undefined in your `addProposal` function. If you want to access proposalId from contract A you should use getter method `a.proposalId()`
2. Second error is that you can't update mapping from another contract. If you want to do that you need to define setter function in your contract A to update mapping and call that setter from contract B.

Comment: So i cannot use proposalId in the addProposal function even when in the constructor of B I have passed the address of A ?

Comment: You can use it with getter method `a.proposalId()`